# Spring Integration: Unit test Start/Stop endpoint adapters

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-integration

I have one jdbc inbound adapter and one jms adapter as follows:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="fooInboundJdbcAdapter" query="SELECT * FROM foo WHERE status IS NULL" channel="fooJdbcChannel"
data-source="dataSource">
   <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="fooJmsMessageDrivenAdapter" 
connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"  
channel="fooJmsListenerChannel" 
destination="fooJmsQueue"/>
```

I used control-bus to start/stop these adapters. One of the method looks like:

```
public boolean startAdapter() {
  return controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@" + fooInboundJdbcAdapter.getComponentName() + ".start()"));
}
```

Now, I am trying to write unit test for above method. I am confused about how I should unit test this method. Any help on this? `controlChannel` and `fooInboundJdbcAdapter` are injected in this case.

Comment: Can you explain the reason to test really Framework stuff? It is the Framework developers to guarantee that those `start/stop` work correctly for end-users.

Comment: I am not trying to test Framework stuff. I am trying to test my method `startAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter needs `auto-startup="false"` to prevent it starting automatically. For you test:

```
startAdapter();
assertTrue(adapter.isRunning();
```

Further to the comments below; add this to your test context...

```
<bean id="fooInboundJdbcAdapter" class="foo.MyTestClassThatImplementsLifecycle" />
```

Comment: I thought of this but this would trigger my real jdbc and jms adapter. I would like to avoid using real adapter when running unit tests.

Comment: So what are you looking to test? You can add a bean to your test config with a bean name that overrides the adapter name; implement `Lifecycle` in your test bean.